# Calculate daily caseload size in dataset using R

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply

This problem has had me scratching my head all day, I'd be very grateful for any help you can provide.

I am trying to calculate the change in size of a health service's caseload over time. So far, I have manipulated the data so that I have a case dataset with three columns:

1. A unique case identifying number
2. A date of referral for that identifying number
3. A date of discharge for that identifying number

```
unique.identifier = c("123456", "789101112", "13141516")
    Referral.date = c("2016-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2014-01-01")
    Discharge.date = c("2017-01-01", "2018-12-04", "2016-02-27")
    df <- data.frame(unique.identifier, Referral.date,     Discharge.date)
```

I think I now need to find a way to calculate the following in some form of loop:

Today's date caseload = (Previous day's caseload + today's referrals - today's discharges)

The end result would be a table, with one column showing daily dates, and another showing the caseload size in numerics.

```
df2 <- data.frame(seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'), as.Date('2019-01-01'), by = "1 days"))
df2$daily.caseload <- sample(1:20, 1827, replace = TRUE)
```

I believe that to solve this, I need to create an object with a full sequence of the dates in the dataset, and then write some sort of loop that carries out this calculation hundreds of times to populate that table. Unfortunately that is currently beyond my skill level!

So far I have tried to follow the guide provided in the CDU data science team's guide here: https://cdu-data-science-team.github.io/team-blog/posts/2022-05-17-caseload-over-time/. However, I can't seem to get my data to group in the way they have, and I am unclear as to how to make it show a change in caseload burden over time.

This example doesn't use sapply, but I think the solution might lie in its use.

What I've written is as far as my imagination and R knowledge can currently take me. Could anyone give me a hint as to how to approach this please?

EDIT:

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. When plotted in ggplot, the data is starting to look like what's needed. However, there are a few issues I've spotted, but can't seem to figure out:

1. The cumulative case_load figure calculated by the summarise function varies wildly. On a day in June 23 I can have a figure in the two-thousands, and the next day it falls to 48.

[Screenshot of part of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4OVD.png)

2. I wonder if cases that are still open are throwing the calculations out? There are many NAs in the Discahrge.Date column where this is the case.

Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please provide a small reproducible example of what you have and what your 
output should be?

Comment: I'll try! One minute...

Comment: There. I hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Your example data doesn't actually match the example output, so I can't test, this, but let me know if this works.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  pivot_longer(                          # restructure the data so we can look at each date separately
    cols = contains("date"),
    names_to = "action",
    names_pattern = "(\\w+)\\.date",
    values_to = 'date'
  ) |>
  summarize(                             # calculate the turnover on each date
    turnover = sum(action == "Referral") - sum(action == 'Discharge'),
      .by = date
  ) |>
  mutate(
    case_load = cumsum(turnover).        # case load is the cumulative sum of the turnover
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much Melissa. I'll give this a go and get back to you!

Comment: Melissa, this worked a treat. I've also found the approach you've used in this problem useful elsewhere in the project. Many thanks!